# Query Firebase list with object value

Tags: android, list, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i am using `DatabaseReference#push` method to add object to reference.
This object has property id.
Next time i have id and i wish to get that user object from that list, how can i get that. I there any simple way to directly Query, or we need to pull all objects and compare each id with the one i require,
here is my object code

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public final class User {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String secret;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(Integer id, String name, String secret) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.secret = secret;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSecret() {
        return secret;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSecret(String secret) {
        this.secret = secret;
    }
}
```

This is how i am adding it to firebase console `mReference.push().setValue(user);` , also i want to know that can we omit thos random generated id for node, becuase i will not be having that kp*** id instead i will be havind id of user object
[image: Firebase image]

Her is how i am try to query more code :)

```
public final class UserReference implements ChildEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = UserReference.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        userList.add(new User(1, "user1", "secret1"));
        userList.add(new User(2, "user2", "secret2"));
    }

    private static final String USER = "users";
    private final DatabaseReference mReference;
    private Query mSingleUserQuery;

    UserReference(FirebaseDatabase database) {
        mReference = database.getReference(USER);
//        mReference.addChildEventListener(this);
    }

    //One time use method
    public void saveUser() {
        for (User user : userList) {
            mReference.push().setValue(user);
        }
    }

    public void findUserById(final String id, final OnDbCompleteListener<User> userListener) {
        mSingleUserQuery = mReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
        mSingleUserQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Logger.info(TAG, "Key: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                sendDataAndUnregister(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Logger.info(TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey());
                sendDataAndUnregister(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Logger.info(TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey());
                sendDataAndUnregister(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Logger.info(TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey());
                sendDataAndUnregister(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                databaseError.toException().printStackTrace();
            }

            private void sendDataAndUnregister(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mSingleUserQuery.removeEventListener(this);
                userListener.onComplete(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Logger.info(TAG, "added: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Logger.info(TAG, "changed: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Logger.info(TAG, "removed: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Logger.info(TAG, "moved: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Logger.info(TAG, "Error: " + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Database Class

```
public final class MySuperCoolDatabase {

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private UserReference mUserReference;

    public MySuperCoolDatabase() {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mUserReference = new UserReference(mDatabase);
    }

    public UserReference getUserReference() {
        return this.mUserReference;
    }
}
```

Its call:

```
MySuperCoolDatabase database = new MySuperCoolDatabase();
        UserReference userReference = database.getUserReference();
        userReference.findUserById("1", new OnDbCompleteListener<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(User user) {
                Logger.info(TAG, "YAYA");
            }
        });
```

DbUpdateListener:

```
public interface OnDbCompleteListener<T> {

    void onComplete(T t);
}
```

Comment: `ref.orderByChild("id").equalTo(1).addChildEventListener(...`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank your for response, i have updated my question with all the necessary classes, still it is not working :'(

Comment: And it worked i missed basics data types mummy  :'( @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @FrankvanPuffelen i had to do following changes, because i was storing id as Integer so i should request for Integer only.

```
public void findUserById(final Integer id, final OnDbCompleteListener<User> userListener) {
        mSingleUserQuery = mReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
...
}
```

From

```
public void findUserById(final String id, final OnDbCompleteListener<User> userListener) {
        mSingleUserQuery = mReference.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);

...
}
```

Also along with this changes i had to add index as suggested in console by firebase war logger here is the rules files

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": false,
        "users": {
            ".indexOn": "id"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For pushing value directly into node, you could use -

```
   User user = "detail of your user";
   // On firebase reference push value on id directly.
   ref.child("1").setValue("user);
```

Here "1" is an id which is going to be primary key for your user detail.

Update -

```
public void saveUser() {
    for (User user : userList) {
        mReference.child(user.id).setValue(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: My code snippet is just an example, you have to replace "detail of your user" with actual detail of user and use correct reference of firebase

Comment: Composing user object is wrong please check above how i composed it any ways question is resolved now

Comment: If you will follow this snippet, you don't need to search id. You can point id directly.

Comment: @sector11, I have updated snippet, please check and let me know it works or not.